# Necessary/sufficient conditions for an infinite product to be exactly equal to $1$

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product

Consider an infinite product $$p=\prod_{n=1}^\infty a_n,$$ with $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$ if possible). Is there an if and only if type theorem for when $p=1$, or is anything known about the nature of the $a_n$ when $p=1$ ?

Clearly one case springs to mind: $a_n=1$ for all $n\geq 1$. Is this the only case or are there others?

**Additionally:** What if the $a_n$ were monotonically increasing or decreasing?

Comment: $$a_{2n-1} = \frac{n^2+1}{n^2};\quad a_{2n} = \frac{n^2}{n^2+1}$$ There's no easy condition. Except $p = 1$ of course.

Comment: $$a_n = \begin{cases}n&odd\\\frac{1}{n-1}&even\end{cases}$$ There are an infinitude of cases possible of course.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. Thanks. Is this still the case if the $a_n$ are monotone decreasing or increasing?

Comment: The limit of the terms better be 1, but if you're strictly monotonically increasing or decreasing, then all terms are on one side of 1, which means the product won't be 1.

Comment: @sabyasachi I don't think those terms have product limit 1, but Daniel ' s example is fine.

Comment: @MarkS. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{2n} a_i=1\times1\times3\times\frac{1}{3}\times\cdots=1$. Isn't that right?

Comment: @sabyasachi yes, but the sequence 3,1,5,1,7,1,... diverges due to oscillation.

Comment: @MarkS. i am forcing an even number of terms in the product though with the $2n$ in the upper limit.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Your example diverges.

Comment: This pretty much the same as asking for necessary and sufficient conditions for an infinite series to sum to exactly zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - so we just take logs and apply the usual tools?

Comment: You bet.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing my comment here since I have not enough reputation to leave a comment. I am not sure on my response. By taking logarithm from both sides we have this:

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_i=0$ in which $b_i=\log{a_i}$

Now we have an infinite summation which is equal to zero and it could have any arrangement. I think we can not say any thing about this since we can have several arrangement that yields the situation. If we consider the situation for finite elements there are several occasions in which the summation is zero and there is not any further relation on elements.

Comment: When $p=1$, taking logarithms gives $\log p=0$ not $\log p=\infty$. Is that a typo?

Comment: @pbs it was a typo since the text said equal to zero.