# Why does this product diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product

Consider the partial product $$ p_n=\prod_{k=1}^{2n}a_k,$$ where $$a_k=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} k & \text{for }k\text{ odd} \\ \frac{1}{k-1} & \text{for }k \text{ even} \end{array}\right..$$ Clearly $p_n=1$ for all natural numbers $n$. But, according to comments left in an [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726597/necessary-sufficient-conditions-for-an-infinite-product-to-be-exactly-equal-to) the limit of partial sums as $n\to\infty$ **diverges**. Why is this so?

Comment: ah from my comment. i wanna see an answer to this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted correctly,

$$\prod_{k=1}^{2n} a_k = 1$$

**but**

$$\prod_{k=1}^{2n+1} a_k = 2n+1$$

which converges to $\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Therefore the sequence of partial products does not converge, i.e. the infinite product

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty a_k$$

does not exist, that is, it diverges.

Comment: This is where I misunderstand. The upper index in the product is **always** $2n$, so by definition the product is never defined with an upper index of $2n+1$. Maybe this is one of those "murky" $\infty$ areas since $\infty$ is not a natural number? ...

Comment: You misunderstand the "sequence of partial products". The sequence of partial products is defined as $a_n=\prod_{k=1}^n a_k$. It runs through *all* natural numbers $n$, even and odd @pbs

Comment: So what your sequence of partial products looks like is: $1,1,3,1,5,1,7,1,9,1,11,\dots$. Does this converge?

Comment: No, his sequence looks like 1,1,1,1.... - his definition of `p_n` was clear about this.

Comment: A product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges if and only if the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log_{e}(a_{n})$ converges. For a series to converge, the sequence of partial sums has to be bounded, which is not true in this case.

Comment: @RohitChatterjee: He is right in saying that the sequence $p_n$ converges (it is constant $1$). But that **does not imply** that the infinite product converges.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson what if take the product defined as $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{i=1}^{2n} a_i$$

Comment: Even if you go through logarithms, `log(p_n)=0` for every n. We are not summing `log(a_n)` an odd number of times

Comment: @Sabyasachi: Yes, then it would be fine. The point is however that the infinite product is **defined** as $\prod_{i=1}^\infty a_i:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \prod_{i=1}^{n} a_i\not=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \prod_{i=1}^{2n} a_i$.

Comment: @TooOldForMath so i take it that is defined somewhere that the infinite product *must* be $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i$? And I can't change the upper limit to an infinity of my choice? I am not saying that $\prod_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ as this, but what if I specify before hand that the upper limit is $2n$?

Comment: @TooOldForMath okay. I wasn't aware of that definition. Then I guess it is settled. My comment on the original post was about this sequence of $p_n$

Comment: @Sabyasachi : Converting the (whole) product to a sum by logs, all the question is saying is that the sequence of partial sums has a convergent subsequence. This does not imply that the whole sequence is convergent.

Comment: @TooOldForMath one last thing. you wrote $\prod_{k=1}^{2n+1} a_k = \frac{1}{2n+1}$. that should be $2n+1$

Comment: @Sabyasachi: Reload.

Comment: @TooOldForMath Yes, you are correct that limits of subsequences are not necessarily limit points of the sequence they are part of. But given the definition of `p_n`, it is true that the limit of `p_n` as n approaches infinity is 1

Comment: @RohitChatterjee: Yes, totally.

Comment: Ok, thanks all I think I've cleared this up now. Basically it all depends on what we mean by an infinite product. Using the standard "sequence of partial products" then we have divergence, but if we explicitly state @Sabyasachi's intention, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{2n}a_n,$$ then we have convergence. Delicate!